# Sitecore - "Some of the automation states could not be written to the database, probably because of expired lock. Record IDs below"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I am using Sitecore 6.5 rev 120706 with DMS 2.0.0.1. Occasionally Sitecore will throw the error

> "Some of the automation states could not be written to the database,
>   probably because of expired lock. Record IDs below"

This then causes the following error:

> "Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1
>   records."

The error seems to be caused by Sitecore Analytics and occurs when users visit the Sitecore site and reach goals on the site. The update commands are related to the automation states.

Does anyone know what could be causing the expired lock in Sitecore? Or how I could narrow down the issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the release notes for Released Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 rev. 121009 (6.5.0 Update-6) and DMS 2.0.1 rev. 121009.

This issue was fixed in that release.  Per the release notes:

> **Issues resolved**
>
> - The log file would fill up with errors messages stating “Some of the
>     automation states could not be written to the database, probably
>     because of expired lock. Record IDs below:  Concurrency
>     violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.”